# selected value of radio button mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC4 project.I am having problem with radio button.

Here is html code for radion button

```
@Html.RadioButton("Radiobtn", "true", new { id = "Radiobtn", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
 Yes
 @Html.RadioButton("Radiobtn", "false", new { id = "Radiobtn", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
 No
```

when i try to get selected value through jquery i am able to see only first radio button value .

Here is jquery code

```
$('#Radiobtn').click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'true') {
                alert('true');
            } else if ($(this).val() == 'false') {
                alert('false');
            }
        });
```

Now alert is shown only if i select first radio button. Nothing is happening on second radio button click ?? I don't know why its not showing alert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are duplicating the `id` attributes, which is invalid, and is why jQuery is only working on click of the first radio. Try using a `class`, like this:

```html
@Html.RadioButton("Radiobtn", "true", new { id = "YesRadio", @class = "radio", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
Yes

@Html.RadioButton("Radiobtn", "false", new { id = "NoRadio", @class = "radio", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
No
```

```js
$('.radio').click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'true') {
        alert('true');
    } 
    else if ($(this).val() == 'false') {
        alert('false');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.Radiobtn').click(function () { //add class on each radiobutton here i take "Radiobtn"
            if ($(this).val()) {
                alert('true');
            } else {
                alert('false');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the duplicate id and try the following:

```
$('input[name=RadioBtn]').on('click', function() {
    // whatever...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have same `id` for both radio button.  Better use **`class`** (but I prefer to use group name for this) and **`change`** event handler.

```
$('.Radiobtn').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'true') {
                alert('true');
            } else if ($(this).val() == 'false') {
                alert('false');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

give a class to your radio buttons,also both should have diff id's.

```
@Html.RadioButton("RadiobtnYes", "true", new { class= "Radio", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
 Yes
 @Html.RadioButton("RadiobtnNo", "false", new { class= "Radio", @style = "width:auto;background:none;border:none" })
 No

$(".Radio").click(function(){
alert(this.val());
})
```

**It will alert `true` or `false` depending upon which radio button was clicked.**